tengo el paquete instalado y me tira el mismo error
Es una aplicación Web MVC con ASP.NET


Estos son mis paquetes Nugget instalados y actualizados a mi versión de .NET (en mi caso es .NET 8.0) y había leído que este error se da debido a que o no se tiene el paquete de Microsfot.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design instalado o actualizado a la versión de .NET que estuvieses usando y lo desinstale y volví a instalar, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, alguien sabe por qué?

No he tocado nada más que no sea la instalación por medio del propio Visual en la sección de examinar, no he utilizado la consola para realizar dicha instalación, solamente lo que se ve en esta ultima imagen.

El error me salta al momento de querer crear un controlador mediante el Scaffolding

Ya tengo el AppDbContext creado y las clases creadas y con sus respectivas relaciones, pero me tira ese error y debido a experiencias anteriores con otros errores, creo que este error no tiene nada que ver con la estructura de las clases utilizadas
Mis modelos:
    public class Cliente
{
    /*Id*/
    [Key]
    [Column("cliente_id")]
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    /*Nit*/
    [Column("nit")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "No mayor de 20 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string NitCliente { get; set; }
    /*Nombre*/
    [Column("nombre")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string NombreCliente { get; set; }
    /*Apellido*/
    [Column("apellido")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string ApellidoCliente { get; set; }
    /*dirrecion*/
    [Column("direccion")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 200 caracteres")]
    public string? DireccionCliente { get; set; }
    /*telefono*/
    [Column("telefono")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "No mayor de 20 caracteres")]
    public string? TelefonoCliente { get; set; }

    /*De cliente a otros*/
    public ICollection<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }
    /*De otros a cliente*/
}
    public class DetallesVentas
{
    /*Id*/
    [Key]
    [Column("detalle_venta_id")]
    public int IdDetallVenta { get; set; }
    /*Relaciones*/
    //venta_id
    [Column("venta_id")]
    public int IdVentaEnDetalleVenta { get; set; }
    //producto_id
    [Column("producto_id")]
    public int IdProductoEnDEtalleVentas { get; set; }
    /*Cantidad*/
    [Column("cantidad")]
    [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Enteros mayores a 0 no deciamles, y menores a 1000 (no deciamles)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public int CantidaddetalleVenta { get; set; }
    /*Precio Unitario*/
    [Column("precio_unitario")]
    [Range(0.1, 1000.1, ErrorMessage = "numeros reales desde 0.1 hasta 1000.1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public decimal PrecioUnitarioDetalleVenta { get; set; }
    /*Subtotal*/
    [Column("subtotal")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000, ErrorMessage = "Numeros desde 0.01 hasta 10000")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public decimal SubTotalDetalleVenta { get; set; }

    /*Variables de relaciones de otros hacia detallesventas*/
    public Venta Venta { get; set; }
    public Producto Producto { get; set; }
}

    public class Empleado
{
    /*Id*/
    [Key]
    [Column("empleado_id")]
    public int IdEmpleado { get; set; }
    /*Nombre Empleado*/
    [Column("nombre")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string NombreEmpleado { get; set; }
    /*Apellido*/
    [Column("apellido")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string ApellidoEmpleado { get; set; }
    /*DPI*/
    [Column("dpi")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "No puede ser mayor a 20 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string DpiEmpleado { get; set; }
    /*Cargo*/
    [Column("cargo")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string CargoEmpleado { get; set; }
    /*Relaciones*/
    /*Id del usuario*/
    [Column("usuario_id")]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    [Required]
    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }

    //De empleado a otros
    public ICollection<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }

    //Variables de las relaciones de otros a empleado
    public ApplicationUser? ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

    public class Producto
{
    /*Id*/
    [Key]
    [Column("producto_id")]
    public int IdProdcuto { get; set; }
    /*Codigo Producto*/
    [Column("codigo")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 50 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string CodigoProducto { get; set; }
    /*Nombre*/
    [Column("nombre")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "No mayor a 100 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public string NombreProducto { get; set; }
    /*Descripción*/
    [Column("descripcion")]
    public string DescripcionProducto { get; set; }
    /*Precio*/
    [Column("precio")]
    [Range(0.1, 10000.01, ErrorMessage = "Desde 0.1 hasta 10000.01")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public decimal PrecioProducto { get; set; }
    /*Stock*/
    [Column("stock")]
    [Range(1, 10000, ErrorMessage = "Desde 1 hasta 10000")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public int StockProducto { get; set; }
    /*foto*/
    /*[Column("foto_url")]
    public string? FotoProducto { get; set; }*/

    /*Variables de relaciones de producto hacia los otros*/
    public ICollection<DetallesVentas> DetallesVentas { get; set; }
    /*Variables de relaciones de otros hacia producto*/

}

    public class Venta
{
    /*Id venta*/
    [Key]
    [Column("venta_id")]
    public int IdVenta { get; set; }
    /*Fecha de la venta*/
    [Column("fecha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede estar vacio")]
    public DateTime FechaVenta { get; set; }
    /*Relaciones*/
    //cliente_id
    [Column("cliente_id")]
    public int IdClienteEnVenta { get; set; }
    //empleado_id
    [Column("empleado_id")]
    public int IdEmpleadoEnVenta { get; set; }
    /*Total Venta*/
    [Column("total")]
    [Range(0.1, 10000.01, ErrorMessage = "Desde 0.1 hasta 10000.01")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No puede ser vacio")]
    public decimal TotalVenta { get; set; }


    /*Variables de relaciones de venta hacia otros*/
    public ICollection<DetallesVentas> DetallesVentas { get; set; }

    /*Variables de relaciones de otros hacia venta*/
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public Empleado Empleado { get; set; }

}

Estos son los modelos que he realizado con base en mi BD y debido a que previamente he tenido problemas con otros proyectos en relación con los modelos, puedo decir que el mensaje no es (por lo menos el que me aparece) en relación con la estructura de los modelos

Hola Rodrigo, en una única aplicación te sucede, o en todas?. si es en una, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y adjuntes eel código relevante.

Es en una, porque me apareció solamente en esta y no tengo idea porque debido a que en otras no me da dicho problema

ere mensaje dice poco, qué dice la consola? Output

Por favor, edita tu pregunta tu adjunta el código (en formato texto).

LPZadkiel
La consola?, lo que aparece abajo?, eso no me dice nada (en el sentido que realmente no pone nada, ni un caracter), ni siquiera aparece.

Marce Puente
Te agradezco, disculpa que hasta ahorita lo haya hecho, pero por lo que investigue tiene que ver con un paquete, pero probé creando otro proyecto e instalando el paquete de nuevo (la versión compatible con mi .NET 8.0) y nanai
